# What do the second player co-op bees do?

Tags: yooka-laylee

I [read](https://www.pcgamesn.com/yooka-laylee/yooka-laylee-multiplayer-arcade-campaign-co-op) that a second player can play as "bees" during the single-player campaign's co-op, but I don't appear to be able to do anything besides look around. How does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did some testing on this (Xbox One). If idle, the second player's bees will disappear, but pressing <kbd>A</kbd> will bring the clunky cursor back up, which the player can move with the analog stick.

The cursor won't automatically pick up **quills**, but if Yooka/Laylee is relatively close to the quill, the second player can press <kbd>A</kbd> over the quill to collect it.

Similarly for **butterflies**, the second player can press <kbd>A</kbd> over nearby butterflies to store them (no immediate effect on the player). The second player can release these from the cursor when later needed with the <kbd>B</kbd> button. I've stored at least three this way—good for when you're hurting for butterflies later. (Not sure what the PC keybinding would be.)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this website](https://www.vg247.com/2017/01/19/yooka-laylee-gets-co-op-multiplayer-modes-and-a-new-gameplay-trailer/):

> The second player will be able to collect butterflies and quills, as well as disarm traps in the world to help the heroes out.

Other than just moving around, that appears to be everything that the second player in coop can do.  The second player is known as "[The Bee Team](http://yooka-laylee.wikia.com/wiki/The_Bee-Team)."  The Wiki page also says that same thing as the linked article above.

Comment: I had seen the site and tried collecting butterflies and quills but clicking didn't do anything, hence why I needed more info

Comment: @Wolf It looks like you just have to fly into the item.  [Video here](https://youtu.be/AERIPwmvp8U?t=20m50s) shows the bee picking up a quill.

Answer (score -1):

You can also hold up some platforms with the bees.

Comment: This seems like it's better suited as a comment on the accepted answer.